# Custom CSS in Jupyter notebook that works in nbviewer

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was reading these two webs that show how to use custom CSS in IPython notebooks published in nbviewer:

http://www.aaronschlegel.com/display-custom-ipython-notebook-themes-in-nbviewer/

https://github.com/titipata/customize_ipython_notebook

Im trying to do the same in a Jupyter notebook. However the code below fails

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import urllib.request
def css():
    style = urllib.request.urlopen('some url with css').read()
    return HTML(style)
css()
```

the URL is [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jackparmer/f9d1b4954df79b4f84ca/raw/9c2a886459e707fc79a551a35272e9e678b1b952/skeleton-ipython-css), Im trying to use the same CSS that is shown in one of the examples.

However trying to run the above code in a cell it throw the error "TypeError: HTML() expects text not b'\n\nhtml..." what is exactly the content of the link!

I did the same operation using the library `requests` instead of `urllib.request` with a similar code and I got the same typeError.

What Im doing wrong? How I can fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `urlopen().read()` method is returning a `bytes` type object rather than a `str`. You can add a `.decode("utf-8")` at the end to convert to `str`.

However, you mentioned attempting to use the `requests` library, and since that is so much nicer for these types of things I'll convert you code to use `requests` that also parses the response into a `str`. You probably tried to use the `.read()` method or something on the `requests` response, when `requests` has a built-in attribute to get the text from a response.

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import requests
def css():
    style = requests.get('http://www.aaronschlegel.com/display-custom-ipython-notebook-themes-in-nbviewer/#viewSource').text
    return HTML(style)
css()
```